# Integer polynomial interpolation (or fast select case)

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

Let `x` in `{10, 37, 96, 104}` set.

Let `f(x)` a *"select case"* function:

```
int f1(int x) {
    switch(x) {
    case 10: return 3;
    case 37: return 1;
    case 96: return 0;
    case 104: return 1;
    }
    assert(...);
}
```

Then, we can avoid conditional jumps writing `f(x)` as a *"integer polynomial"* like

```
int f2(int x) {
    // P(x) = (x - 70)^2 / 1000
    int q = x - 70;
    return (q * q) >> 10;
}
```

In some cases (still including `mul` operations) would `f2` better than `f1` (eg. large conditional evaluations).

Are there methods to find `P(x)` from a `switch` injection?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Given `n` points you can always find a `n-1`th degree polynomial to fit them, and sometimes (as here) you'll get lucky and there'll be a lower degree polynomial that fits. Don't know how you'd find that, ask [math.se] maybe. BUT... don't do this unless it's demonstrably a performance bottleneck AND your alternative is quicker. I suspect that combination will be rare.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start reading the Wikipedia page about  [Polynomial Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), if you do not know how to calculate the interpolation polynomial.

Note, that not all calculation methods are suitable for practical application, because of numerical issues (e.g. divisions in the Lagrange version). I am confident that you shold be able to find a libary providing this functionality. Note that the construction will take some time too, hence this makes only sence if your function will be called quite frequently.

Be aware that integer function values and integer points of support do not imply integer coefficients for your polynomial! Thus, in the general case, you will require O(n) floating point operations, and finally a round toward the nearest integer. It may depend on your input wether the interpolation method is reliable and faster than the approach using switch.

Further, I want to propose a differnt solution, assuming that n is rather large. Why dont you put your entries (the pairs (10,3), (37,1), (96,0), (104,1) for your example) inside a serchtree (e.g. std::map in C++ or SortedDictionary in C#)? Thus, your query cost would reduce from linear to O(log n)!

Comment: Yes I know, but traditional polynomial interpolation is not useful (at least, directly). A interpolation would set a constant value to 1000 but 1024 is better (shift vs imul). In general, exist infinite curves (in rational space) that satisfy n-points. I ask if a related method exist. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you unroll your code, you get better (much better) performance than (eg) a map. I use above to speedup in some cases but I don't know if a method exist.